# Button is not Clickable or not getting any response

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Html Code for Button Submit in JSP:

```
  <button type="button" class="btnInactive" name="Save" id="saveGrid" 
  onclick="saveList()">
 <img src="<c:url value="/images/save.png" />" alt="Save" title="Save" 
  class="vMiddle padRight5"> <spring:message code="label.save"/></button>
```

Html Code for mouseover button:

```
  <button onclick="saveList()" id="saveGrid" name="Save" class="btnInactive"
  type="button" disabled="disabled">
  <img class="vMiddle padRight5" title="Save" alt="Save" 
  src="/web/images/save.png"> Save </button>
```

---

I Tried this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='saveGrid']/img")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button#saveGrid")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button#saveGrid")).click();
```

Comment: What kind of error are you receiving?

Comment: No error is throwing. Test suite was shown Success and in Console there is no error or insert queries are shown.

Comment: I cant see a closing button tag

Comment: Sorry I missed that. But it is not the problem.

Comment: Above button style is using in every page of my project. We tried in many ways. But can't succeed. Button style should not be changed. Its fixed. But I am trying to insert values into Database. But no Response.

Comment: Have you tried accessing through name instead of cssSelector?

Comment: Yes I tried. Here in the above HTML Code, When we move cursor on button it is in Active State and undo cursor it is going to disable state. How can I handle?

Comment: `if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$('[name=Save]').trigger('mouseover')");
 }`

This should simulate a mouse movement over the button

Comment: Why do you click the button, then wait, and then try to click again?

Comment: Why is the button disabled by default `disabled="disabled"` ? How is it enabled ? Click wont work unless its enabled.

Comment: Hi,

For the first code id="saveGrid" works like charme.

but for the second part of the code you have to remove disabled="disabled" after that only you can proceed with click as @Mad Piranha said.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because there might be one more button with same property , so try to find element uniquely then try.
Ex: Two button having same attributes at that time webdriver will fail so user in case of multiple element having same property try to find element uniquely with relative xpath